# How to convert MySQL data to JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

How to encode JSON in below format:

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
     "JobID":"1",
     "JobTitle":"CEO"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I achieved:

```
[
  {
    "JobID":"1",
    "JobTitle":"CEO"
  }
]
```

Here is my PHP script using to mysql data to JSON:

```
<?php
    ......

    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE 1 ";

    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
    $resultArray = array();
    while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

I am not a native PHP developer, that's why not so strong in web development and i tried some tutorials and blogs but did not get any solution !

Comment: use echo json_encode("jobs"=>array($resultArray));

Comment: (Finding duplicates is difficult for such trivial questions, because nobody bothers with even remotely descriptive question titles.)

Comment: Change your echo to:

echo json_encode(array('jobs' =>$resultArray));

and you have what you're looking for exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this it should work ..

$jobarray = array();

$jobarray['jobs']  = $resultArray;

echo json_encode($jobarray);

Comment: thanks for solution, i already ticked your answer as well and after 7 minutes i will accept this